# 301 redirect htaccess /%E2%80%8E

Tags: php, .htaccess

No soy capaz de redirigir una www.miweb.com/%E2%80%8E hacía www.miweb.com

He probado con htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /%E2%80%8E http://www.miweb.com
```

Php

```
$cadena = 'http://www.miweb.com/%E2%80%8E';
if(preg_match('/\/%E2%80%8E/', $cadena)){
    header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
    header( "Location: http://www.google.es" );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "%E2%80%8E" 
RewriteRule . http://www.example.com [L,R=301]
```

Hay que usar `%{THE_REQUEST}` para matchear la solicitud antes de que sea decodeada, por eso

```
RewriteRule "%E2%80%8E" http://www.example.com [L,R=301]
```

no funciona, pero esto sí:

```
RewriteRule "â€Ž" http://www.example.com [L,R=301]
```

Además parece que estás redirigiendo dentro del mismo servidor, entonces no necesitas ponerle `http://loquesea/blahblah`, puedes hacerlo así:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "%E2%80%8E" 
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Podrias agregar una descripción para que el usuario sepa porque sirve y no solo lo copie y pegue en su codigo, asi ganaras mas reputación de la comunidad ;)

Comment: ya está jefe :)

Comment: Perfecto, asi mas gente valorara mejor tus aportes y podras ayudar a mas usuarios =)

Comment: Gracias @Vrac! Funciona perfectamente. Es un problema bastante común, espero que les sirva también a otros usuarios.

Comment: @Vrac, me funciona el planteamiento que pusiste tu pero me falta una cosa para completar. La URL que tengo yo es: http://www.garden.com/index.php/xxxx/xxxx/New%20Private%20Message/enrique-iglesias-espana-debe-ampliar-alianzas-con-america-latina Y no me copia la parte de detrás del valor que he sustituido. Sabes si necesito poner algo mas? RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "New%20Private%20Message" RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]

Answer (score 0):

Sobreescribe simplemente la norma:

```
RewriteRule /\xE2\x80\x8E$ http://www.miweb.com [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Gracias Miguel. Recibo un error 500

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
$cadena = 'http://www.miweb.com/%E2%80%8E';
if(preg_match('/%E2%80%8E/', $cadena))
{
    $urlRedireccion = "http://www.google.es";
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: $urlRedireccion");
}
```

EDICIÓN:

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.location.replace("http://www.google.es");
</script>
<?php
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Tampoco funciona, no creo que haya alguna diferencia guardando la url en $urlRedireccion.

Comment: Sabes si entra en el `if`??

Comment: Entra ya que si le pongo un echo dentro me muestra el texto. Intente también guardar los datos en buffer antes de lanzar los header porque pensaba que se trataba de un error de cabeceras, pero no.

Comment: He añadido otra posible solución, prueba haber si se soluciona @Webly

Comment: Gracias Alberto, pero necesito que sea un 301